# How can I carry the output of my XOR gate into my AND gate using functions?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am able to define first set of gates inputs and produce outputs from according gates. 
I am trying to use the output of previous gate  and use them in my newer set of gates.

For example, I have an input that is set to 0 called PREV and a variable called XOR which takes the output from the first XOR gate so it can be reused.

---

Program code:

```
   #we will be solving the second AND/XOR gates.
   def AND_MK2(XOR,PREV):
   #we define inputs of first XOR gate and PREV; new inputs enter new 
   gates.
       if XOR == 0 and PREV == 0:
           AND_5(XOR,PREV) #again, based on the condition we call 
           different functions.
           print("Now solve the XOR gate otherwise move on")
           gate_path_B ()
       elif XOR == 1 and PREV == 0:
           AND_6(XOR,PREV)
           print("Now solve the XOR gate otherwise move on")
           gate_path_B ()
       else:
           print("Error")

   #since the inputs can only be 00 or 10; PREV is = 0
   def AND_5(XOR,PREV): #called into the main program
       print(XOR , " AND " , PREV , " = 0")
       AND_II = 0 #stores output in variable for later use

   def AND_6(XOR,PREV):
       print(XOR , " AND " , PREV , " = 0")
       AND_II = 0

   #Program starts here by defining the inputs
   A = None
   while A is None:
       try:
           A = int(input("Enter a number 1 or 0: "))
       except ValueError:
           print("You didn't enter either number")
   print(str(A));

   B = None
   while B is None:
       try:
           B = int(input("Enter a number 1 or 0: "))
   except ValueError:
       print("You didn't enter either number")
  print(str(B));

def gate_path_A (): #type any of the three numbers given for their option
    print("Press 3 for MOVE")
    x = int(input("write 1/2/3: "))

    if x == 3:
        gate_path_B()
    else:
        print("error")

def gate_path_B (): #same fundamentals to gate path A but different 
options given
    print("Press 1 for AND_MK2")
    print("Press 3 for MOVE")
    y = int(input("write 1/2/3: "))

    if y == 1:
        AND_MK2(XOR,PREV)
    elif y == 2:
        XOR_MK2(XOR,PREV)
    elif y == 3:
        gate_path_C()
    else:
        print("error")

gate_path_A()
gate_path_B()

PREV = None
while PREV is None:
    try:   
        PREV = 0 #No actual inputs take place
    except ValueError:
        print("Inputs only 0; we have not input in the first place")
print(str(PREV));

XOR = None #we will define XOR based on the output of its first gate.
while XOR is None:
    try:
        XOR(XOR,PREV)
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect")
print(str(XOR));

#defines our two logic gates with the given inputs
first_AND (A,B)
first_XOR (A,B)
AND_MK2(XOR,PREV);
XOR_MK2(XOR,PREV);
```

---

I am just new to the whole debugging process of finding where is the error exists but the main problem is I get an

```
error : gate_path_B is not defined in my AND_MK2 or the XOR_MK2.
```

If you need additional information about the program execution and what results are produced please mention in a comment.

Errors produced during execution phase

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
  systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 169, in <module>
  gate_path_A()
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
   systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 146, in 
   gate_path_A
first_AND (A,B)
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 7, in first_AND
gate_path_A()
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 148, in gate_path_A
first_XOR (A,B)
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 43, in first_XOR
gate_path_A()
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 150, in gate_path_A
gate_path_B()
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Coursework\Python Cicruits\Test MK5.py", line 161, in gate_path_B
AND_MK2(XOR,PREV)
NameError: name 'XOR' is not defined
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can demonstrate your problem with a *much* smaller example. There is far too much irrelevant code in this question.

Comment: I had that feeing chepnerill just filter what isnt relevant an put up relevance content

Comment: There made changes to the program an made the example above wayyy smaller sorry if you all had to see so much I cropped it down to transfer of one gate to another then the part of solving the AND MK2 gate

Comment: Can you please post the FULL traceback as an edit to your question?

Comment: ohh you mean you want a copy of the whole program code rather than the cut down version?

Comment: No, the full ERROR. For example: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Attoa\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    yops()
NameError: name 'yops' is not defined`

Comment: Alright Ill send the errors that pop up during the program execution for ya. Ill post it above

Comment: It would also help if you explain what this program is actually supposd to do. It looks like you're simulating logic gates. Are you trying to build a binary adder circuit? If so, you're making it _way_ too complicated!

Comment: Yes PM you are right there I am creating an adder circuit.

Comment: In the lines `if y == 1:
        AND_MK2(XOR,PREV)
    elif y == 2:
        XOR_MK2(XOR,PREV)`, XOR (and PREV) are never defined, what do you want this to do?

Comment: Just incase anyone wants to know what the program does this is how it starts: first the user is prompted to enter two inputs for A and B which will choose 0 and 0. Next we will be asked to type 1 2 or 3 based on the statements from print to solve either the and gate the XOR gate or solve the next set of gates. the AND and XOR will take inputs compare the two  values call a function which deal with the two inputs and creates its output. the move on will take us to our next set of gates which i expect to perform the same thing but with my outputs from the previous gates but thats a halt there.

Comment: @Atto I wen it says XOR and PREV I plan on assigning those as inputs into my set of gates so for example I will type 1 to solve the second AND gate otherwise type 2 to solve the second XOR gate. once we select our gate I expect the program to take the stored outputs of our previous gates and store it in those variables for use.

Comment: I dont understand how it is able to identify the inputs of A and B but not my variables of XOR and PREV? could this be to do with the boundaries of global an local variables

Comment: in `gate_path_B()` can you put `print(XOR)` to see if it actually is defined

Comment: Nope I put a print statement and it prints nothing in there... So that is a good indication that XOR hasn't been defined properly

Comment: You have lot more error in the program you posted initially , First of all python is case sensitive you have a function defined as SUM_2 , but have used Sum_2  , and at lot more other places

Comment: Wish it were possible to send an image of the gate to give you all a visual understanding of what I am trying to create. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code. Variables defined inside a function only exist inside that function, they can't be seen by other functions. So you need to change how your functions interact.

None of you functions return what they calculate, so they will return `None`. So you need to put `return` statements in your functions and when you call a function you need to save what it returns so it can be passed to other functions, &/or printed.

Also, there is *far* too much repetition in your code. Don't define a bunch of functions that all perform the same operation. That defeats the main purpose of defining functions in the first place. Make a function that performs a given task, and each time you need to perform that task, use that function.

Here's some code to get you started. It doesn't read any user input, I'll let you handle that job. Instead, it uses the `product` function from the standard `itertools` module to create bit patterns to feed to the logic gates.

```
from itertools import product

def and_gate(a, b):
    return a & b

def xor_gate(a, b):
    return a ^ b

def half_adder(a, b):
    sum_bit = xor_gate(a, b)
    carry_bit = and_gate(a, b)
    return carry_bit, sum_bit 

def full_adder(a, b, c):
    c0, s0 = half_adder(a, b)
    c1, s = half_adder(c, s0)
    c = xor_gate(c0, c1)
    return c, s

# Test

bits = (0, 1)
print('Half-adder test')
for a, b in product(bits, repeat=2):
    c, s = half_adder(a, b)
    print('{} + {} = {} {}'.format(a, b, c, s))

print('\nFull-adder test')
for c, a, b in product(bits, repeat=3):
    c1, s = full_adder(a, b, c)
    print('{} + {} + {} = {} {}'.format(c, a, b, c1, s))
```

**output**

```
Half-adder test
0 + 0 = 0 0
0 + 1 = 0 1
1 + 0 = 0 1
1 + 1 = 1 0

Full-adder test
0 + 0 + 0 = 0 0
0 + 0 + 1 = 0 1
0 + 1 + 0 = 0 1
0 + 1 + 1 = 1 0
1 + 0 + 0 = 0 1
1 + 0 + 1 = 1 0
1 + 1 + 0 = 1 0
1 + 1 + 1 = 1 1
```

Comment: Holy cow PM you just destroyed my aspirations XD but that is freaking epic and the code is sooo well maintained compared with mine I can see why people here are pros. But isn't there a possible way in which my version of the code can be fixed to make it possible to work? or is it just badly maintained

Comment: Ohhh I get it you want me to study this example then apply it to my own code in order for me to solve the problem. That is exactly what I will plan on doing.

Comment: Thanks yall for the helpouts I have observed one problem leads to another as I have explored with python. Before I programmed using Visual basic

Comment: @PL8YR Well, you _could_ try to repair your code, but it may be easier to just chuck it and start again from scratch. ;) But yes, I wrote this to show you how to write functions that return results and how those results can be passed into other functions. BTW, we normally use lower-case names for functions and simple variables in Python. Names that are all upper-case are used for constants. That's not a hard rule, but it is the standard style, and it will make it easier for other people to read your code if you follow that style.

Comment: Thats the funny story PM now would be too late if I chuck the code XD.So I am better off understanding your example, work with mine to fix the problem because 9 days from now I will have to hand in my final program because this is part of my coursework but I will take your advice on maintaining code especially the functions to do with the AND and XOR gates because I realised I could actually reduce the quantity of code in there. :)